# vtiger CRM - 7.1.0 - How to find the Invite Users actions?

Tags: workflow, crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

I want to implement the Invite User actions located in the Calendar>Events to Project.

I've tried searching in the Workflows and other settings but I couldn't find where is the actions located.

Answer (score 0):

Invtite Users does not have any UI for configuration. you have to modify the following files for your customization.

modules/Events/models/Module.php | function -> **saveRecord** | Between lines -> 28-40
modules/Events/models/Record.php | function -> **getInviteUserMailData**| Between lines -> 136-189
modules/Calendar/CalendarCommon.php | function -> **sendInvitation**| Between lines -> 150-181